# How to create AutoForm field in Meteor to select a record from another collection and save it as a subdocument?

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

I've been struggling with this for a couple of hours and I can't find a good solution so maybe someone can shed a light on this.

I have a simple schema like this:

```
    var groupschema = new SimpleSchema({
      name: {
        label: 'Name',
        type: String
      },
      description: {
        label: 'Description',
        type: String
      }
    }
```

And I have another one:

```
    var itemschema = new SimpleSchema({
      name: {
        label: 'Type:',
        type: String
      },
      details: {
        label: 'Details',
        type: String
      },
      group: [groupschema] // <--- this is my main interest
    }
```

If I use the above code sample AutoForm will generate an "inner form" which is quite cool actually for some puporse (e.g. for a contact to have an array of adresses or phone numbers) but for me I would like a drop-down select with the name of the group and when I click on the Insert/Update button (depending on the current form) I would like to add the whole group document to the inserted/updated item document as a subdocument.

Something like this will be inserted to the mongodb:

```
{
    _id: the generated mongoid,
    name: "This is a type",
    details: "There are some thing to know about this type",
    group:{
        name: "Cool group",
        description: "This is a really cool group"
    }
}
```

The actual documents are far more complicated the above example is just an oversimplified version.

I've stopped writing this question yesterday and tried to do my own version.

My - half baked - solution is:

- introducing a new field in the schema named groupselect (type string, autoform type: select)
- populate it's contents with a Collection.find().map() lookup

`groupselect: { 
    type: String,
    label: 'Group',
    optional: true,
    blackbox: true,
    autoform:{
        type: "select",
        options : function() {
                return Issuegroup.find().map(function (c) {
                   return {label: c.name , value: c._id};
               });
        }
    }

  },`

- using autoform hooks before insert I assign the subdocument to the real fiel `group = Group.find({_id:doc.groupselect})` and I remove the helper field from the doc
- using the same technique in the before update hook also for an update form

The problem I seem to be unable to solve in a clean way is to set the default value of the helper field 'groupselect' when the update form displays. I've tried the docToForm hooks but no luck.

Isn't this somehow a very common problem? I imagine there has to be a proper solution for this so I bet that I am missing something very obvious and hopefully someone will point it out for me.

Thanks

Comment: Similar problem here. I am currently unwiring all those autoFrom subdocument inputs into a generic component, which inserts all subdocuments into their own collection and saves only the id as a ref into the array of the parent doc. If I come up with something useful, I will post it.